# IOS Safari -- Links at bottom of screen require double tap

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, ios, safari

I have some links in a fixed position div at the bottom of the screen. The problem however is that on IOS, the first tap on a link in this position does not follow the link. Instead, the UI of the browser appears (bottom and top bar). A second tap is required to actually navigate to the link page.

Is there any way to eliminate this behavior? I tried to attach myself to touchstart and touchend events to redirect the page via jquery, but that accomplished nothing.

```
$(".action.navigation a").on("click touchstart touchend", function(e) {
  e.preventDefault();
  window.location.href = $(this).attr("href");
});
```

Comment: Can't say for sure, but that's built into the browser to help the user get back to the chrome of safari. Probably not a way around it unfortunately.